# YouTube 360 videos will play but the view is stationary

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, sony-xperia, youtube

I'm using Sony Xperia M2 phone on Android Lollipop 5.1, and the YouTube app with latest update. Any video that supports 360 view will play, but the view is stationary - I can't move it around.

Answer (score 1):

To watch 360° videos your phone should support a gyroscope sensor. A gyroscope gives the phone's pitch tilt and yaw, which is needed by the YouTube app to properly rotate the view on display.